# docker-compose run , Link to previously running container

Tags: nginx, docker, docker-compose

I have 2 containers that I want to run with "docker-compose run" for bash iteraction. My composer file look like the one bellow

```
--- 
services: 
  dataBase: 
    image: "mysql:latest"
    container_name: dataBase
    environment: 
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: SOME_PASSWORD
      MYSQL_DATABASE: SOME_DATABASE
    ports:
      - "3306:3306"
    volumes: 
      - ../data:/var/lib/mysql
  api:
    build: builds/web
    container_name: api
    hostname: "api"
    ports:
      - "5000:5000"
    external_links:
      - dataBase
    volumes: 
      - ../api:/etc/api
    working_dir: /etc/api
    command: npm start
  nginx:
    image: nginx:1.11.13-alpine
    ports:
      - "8080:80"
    volumes: 
      - ../nginx/conf.d:/etc/nginx/conf.d/
    external_links:
      - api:api
    restart: always
version: "3"
```

I do:

```
docker-compose run --service-ports api bash
```

That initializes the api container with the link to database.
And then I need the nginx to run and be linked to API, I could not do that yet. I am doing:

```
docker-compose run -d --service-ports --no-deps nginx
```

Is there a way for me to make these 2 runs separated and still achieve the nginx linking. I tried external_link but that didn't cut it.

Comment: It is unclear what you are trying to accomplish. Why not just `docker-compose up` and a separate `docker-compose run api bash`?

Comment: I actually want to have 2 bashs linked because I would use for development purposes (one on api and one on other container, still not created). I was using NGINX as a guinea pig to make it work (the linking part)

Comment: Additionally the nginx is a reverse proxy, so if I run api the nginx won't have a linking to it causing the reverse proxy to fail

Answer (score 1):

Found a workaround.
What I did was starting using networks (links would work all the same is just that they are [legacy](https://docs.docker.com/engine/userguide/networking/default_network/dockerlinks/)).

The trick is making the container I want to access to sleep and then acessing it through **docker-compose exec**.

My file look like the one bellow:

```
--- 
services: 
  dataBase: 
    image: "mysql:latest"
    container_name: dataBase
    environment: 
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: SOME_PASSWORD
      MYSQL_DATABASE: SOME_DATABASE
    volumes: 
      - ../data:/var/lib/mysql
    networks:
      - proxy
  api:
    build: builds/web
    container_name: api
    hostname: api
    ports:
      - "5000:5000"
    depends_on:
      - dataBase
    volumes: 
      - ../api:/etc/api
    working_dir: /etc/api
    networks:
      - proxy
    command: "sleep infinity" #keeps the container alive for 2 way networking to work, test is ran with docker-compose exec
  nginx:
    image: nginx:1.11.13-alpine
    container_name: nginx
    hostname: nginx
    ports:
      - "8080:80"
    volumes: 
    - ../nginx/conf.d:/etc/nginx/conf.d/
    restart: always
    depends_on:
      - api
    networks:
      - proxy
networks:
  proxy:
    driver: bridge
version: "3"
```

The catch is the command "sleep infinity" so my workflow now is:

```
docker-compose up
docker-compose exec api bash
```

I found the solution on this [issue](https://github.com/docker/compose/issues/4052).

I think it is good enough even though if I could get away without the sleep trick I would be happier, mostly because I wanted to leave the production command on the composer.